# Add extra property in Symfony model

Tags: symfony

I want to add new properties to existing Entity without creating the new column in database.

Let'say we have defined an entity with 2-3 columns `id, name, score`.

Now when we query using `findAll` etc. methods I need to get additional value `average`. So we are expecting 4 fields whenever we query specific entity.

Can we achieve this using getter/setters or any other solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can simply create an additional getter on the entity class which calculates the average on the fly:

```
public function getAverage()
{
    // calculate the $average;
    return $average;
}
```

If the calculation of the average is expensive, you can cache the result in a private property and return that on subsequent calls to the getter.

Comment: But simply creating getter will not return any value. It will still load only defined properties. Note: I have not defined `average`property.

Comment: It doesn’t matter if there’s an `average` property. The “getter” is just some method that returns a value. Calculate the value inside the `getAverage` method and return it.